# Cann't make installation of npm in my Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, npm

I need a Help.I have made a Laravel Project and I want to install npm in it.
I am typing "npm install" but I am getting following Error.[image]

I have installed last version of python, npm and node. But when I am trying to install fibers I am getting following:
[image]

If someone knows what going on here please write it.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Try running with **sudo**. `sudo npm install`

Comment: ^ you should never run npm install with sudo !

Answer (score 1):

It seem you are using windows. For that you need to install required tools first. You can do this using Microsoft's windows-build-tools  by executing the below command

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

Then  `npm install`

[Microsoft -> Nodejs Guidline](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration)

Comment: You should also update your nodejs version. It seems to be 0.12 while the latest one is 12.x

Comment: I have downloaded latest version of node js from official site and installed it. I donn't know why it is still showing me it

Comment: with nvm I have installed last version of node and now when I am typing "node --version" it is showing me "v12.16.1"

Comment: When I run your command "npm install -g windows-build-tools" it is gving me another error. SOmething like:  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'EPERM',

Comment: open your terminal as an administrator by right click then run this command